# find records in a table which is not associated in to other records in different table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables :

```
list_routes
pk_route_id  route_code  route_name route_description
3              J1          IND           IND-DPS
4              J4          ADT           ADT_DPS

tbl_stu_route
pk_stu_route_id    fk_stu_cls_id   fk_route_id
2                    13               3

tbl_stu_class
pk_stu_cls_id  fk_stu_id  
 13                56
```

Now what I want to achieve is write query in MYSQL that it will fetch me the records from list_routes which is not associated or attached  in tbl_stu_class so for e.g in the above scenario it should give me the output :

```
pk_route_id  route_code  route_name route_description
4              J4          ADT           ADT_DPS
```

I wrote the below query using left outer join as

```
SELECT
    a.pk_route_id,
    a.route_code,
    a.route_name,
    a.route_description
FROM
    list_routes a
left outer join tbl_stu_route b on a.pk_route_id=b.fk_route_id
left outer join tbl_stu_class c on b.fk_stu_cls_id=c.pk_stu_cls_id
where c.fk_stu_id ='56'
```

but the output was

```
pk_route_id  route_code  route_name route_description
3              J1          IND           IND-DPS
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong. Can you please enlighten me how to acieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the *not exists* record then just filter out with `IS NULL`

```
SELECT a.*
FROM list_routes a
left outer join tbl_stu_route b on a.pk_route_id=b.fk_route_id
left outer join tbl_stu_class c on b.fk_stu_cls_id=c.pk_stu_cls_id
where b.fk_route_id is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the nature of your question, I would use `not exists`:

```
SELECT lr.*
FROM list_routes lr
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM tbl_stu_route sr JOIN
                       tbl_stu_class c 
                       ON sr.fk_stu_cls_id = c.pk_stu_cls_id
                  WHERE lr.pk_route_id = sr.fk_route_id AND
                        c.fk_stu_id = 56
                 );
```

Notes:

- When using table aliases, use abbreviations for the table names.  Abbreviations make the query much easier to follow than random letters.
- Do not use single quotes for numeric constants.  I assume that your ids are numbers, hence `56` rather than `'56'`.
- I find that `NOT EXISTS` is a better fit to your problem description than `LEFT JOIN`, although both work.